# Define property is not defined in sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am writing with such a question, I did not find relevant information in the official documentation, or Google.

I have a server (nodejs , express , typescript, sequelize )

In the server.service.ts file, I initialize and configure the desired config

```js
// File --> server.service.ts

const sequelize: Sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, {
   dialect: "mysql",
   host: DB_HOST,
   pool: { idle: 10000, max: 10, min: 0 },
});

export {sequelize} // e.t.c.

// I use barrel way to export & imports
```

Then I go to the models directory, and create a regular user model:

```js
import { DataTypes, ModelDefined, Optional } from "sequelize";
import { Role, User as Usr } from "../types";
import { sequelize } from "../services";

type UserOptionalsAttr = Optional<Usr, "id" | "role">;

const User: ModelDefined<Usr, UserOptionsAttr> = sequelize.define(
   "User",
   {
     email: {
       allowNull: false
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       unique: true
       validate: { isEmail: true },
     },
     id: {
       autoIncrement: true
       onDelete: "CASCADE",
       onUpdate: "CASCADE",
       primaryKey: true
       type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     },
     password: {
       allowNull: false
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       validate: { max: 16, min: 3 },
     },
     role: {
       allowNull: false
       defaultValue:Role.USER,
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
     },
     username: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING },
   },
   { tableName: "users", timestamps: true }
);
export { User };
```

As a result, I use this model in controllers for logging in and registering users, where I use the model to search for existing users:

```js
   const foundedUser = await User.findOne({
       where: { email },
     });

// further checks with their answers
```

As a final result I get an error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'define'). You can fix it if you describe the models in the service ... Which is not entirely correct. Help

Comment: You have not provided how you export the `sequelize` variable in `server.service.ts`, which could be causing the issue. Could you share how you have done this?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that this is required. (i update my question & add export from server.service to other files (for all app))

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks for that! Can you `console.log(sequelize)` in the file where you define your models? If it logs "undefined" or nothing, you haven't exported or imported correctly. Otherwise, could you post the type of result you get? If all is well, it'll return a class with a "define()" method in!

Comment: I don't see where you pass the Sequelize instance variable `sequelize` to the `define` method

Comment: Passing an instance is only necessary when using the class approach of creating a model